# Check Word Document Style for every single lines

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word Document with mixed styles and need to add HTML tags if the line matches h1, h2 or h3.
I'm trying to save the new string into an array and save as .html file
But have no idea how to write the if condition in .vba, so please help.

```
Public Sub Word2HTML()
    Dim NewArray() As String
    Dim TextFile As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = "C:\Temp\final.html"
    TextFile = FreeFile
    'Open the text file
    Open FilePath For Output As TextFile
    
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        ' error on the next line
        If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style.Text = "Heading 1" Then
            ReDim Preserve NewArray(i-1)
            NewArray(i-1) = "<h1>" + ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i) + "</h1>"
        Elseif ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style.Text = "Heading 2" Then
            ReDim Preserve NewArray(i-1)
            NewArray(i-1) = "<h2>" + ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i) + "</h2>"
        Elseif ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style.Text = "Heading 3" Then
            ReDim Preserve NewArray(i-1)
            NewArray(i-1) = "<h3>" + ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i) + "</h3>"
        Else
        End If
    Next i
    
    For Each headline In NewArray
        Print #TextFile, headline
    Next
    Close TextFile

End Sub
```

Here is the error message I got from MS Word VB

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following captures all headings and saves them to an HTML file with the same name as the active document:

```
Sub HeadingsToHTML()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, h As Long
With ActiveDocument
  With .Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = "<strong>^&</strong>"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "</strong>^&<strong>"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  Set Rng = .Range(0, 0)
  Set Rng = .TablesOfContents.Add(Range:=Rng, UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
    UpperHeadingLevel:=1, LowerHeadingLevel:=9, IncludePageNumbers:=False).Range
  Rng.Fields.Unlink
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Rng.End = .Range.End
  Rng.Delete
  With .Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    For h = 1 To 9
      .Style = "TOC " & h
      .Text = "([!^13]{1,})"
      .Replacement.Text = "<h" & h & ">\1</h" & h & ">"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
  End With
  .SaveAs2 FileName:=Split(.FullName, ".doc")(0) & ".html", FileFormat:=wdFormatText, AddToRecentFiles:=False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Way faster than looping through all paragraphs, too.

If your headings have level #s and you don't want those in the output, replace:

```
  .Text = "([!^13]{1,})"
```

with:

```
  .Text = "[!^13]@^t([!^13]{1,})"
```

Comment: Amazing! I forgot to mention some lines have Bold words which i need to add <strong> tag, so what's the trick to find them out?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to bold words in headings, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Styles do not have a `.Text` property. You probably are trying to do this:

```
If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style = "Heading 1" Then

  ' do something here

End If
```